# Command in batch file in Windows

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, batch

I have the customer display Logic Control LD9000 and POS software, on customer display I want set normal display mode, so I send in CMD in Windows

```
 ECHO ^Q>COM1
```

The display changes display mode well. But i want used this in POS software, i configure start.bat.

```
MODE COM1:9600,N,8,1
ECHO ^Q>COM1
```

When I run POS software, command only displays "Q" on customer display.

This is from user manual LD9000.

> Commands are transmitted to the pole display as ASCII codes.  The
>   command codes listed below are expressed in:

- > Hexadecimal (base 16)
  >   numbers enclosed inside angle brackets < >
- Decimal numbers

  > enclosed in parenthesis ( )
- ASCII characters

  > enclosed in curlybrackets { }.  Do not include the brackets as part of the command.  ‘
  >   ^ ‘ character denotes ‘Ctrl’ in the keyboard.  Press and hold ‘Ctrl’,
  >   then press the next key

> Command Set :
>   Normal Display Mode <11> or (17) or {^Q}

I tried in CMD send with brackets and without brackets this:

```
echo  <11>>COM1
  echo (17)>COM1
```

But this only displays as number on customer display.
Thank you, if anyone know where I a make mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with POS software in regards to sending an eject code for the till which used COM1 - I'm sure there is a better way than this, but I used autohotkey to open a cmd window and type 'echo  > com1 (enter)' then exit. You can set the variables of the cmd window to start minimised. Use autohotkey typecode.ahk (typecode.ahk being the script above) to run.

I had to adopt this method due to every machine it was run on dealt differently with escape codes / ANSI.SYS.